# random writing Markov Model efficiency

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here is my implementation 
However, it is a bit slow when analyzing the textfile, 
Anyone have a better idea or better data structure to implement Random writing?
Im not using the STL library so dun worry about the syntax. 
instead of using push_back, vector here is using .add

randomInteger will generate randome integer between ranges

I would like to produce 2000 character if possible;

I think the slowest part is reading the file char by char?

```
void generateText(int order, string initSeed, string filename){
    Map<string , Vector<char> > model;
    char ch;
    string key;
    ifstream input(filename.c_str());
    for(int i = 0; i < order; i++){
        input.get(ch);
        key+=ch;
    }
    while(input.get(ch)){
        model[key].add(ch);
        key = key.substr(1,key.length()-1) + ch;
    }
    string result;
    string seed = initSeed;
    for(int i = 0;i<2000;i++){
        if (model[seed].size() >0) {
            ch = model[seed][randomInteger(0, model[seed].size()-1)];
            cout << ch;
            seed = seed.substr(1,seed.length()-1) + ch;
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im using macbk Air 2012, cause i got a a demo program which run much faster than mine. And I'm curious about why the demo can run faster.

Comment: Im putting a text file about 1.8MB in this function. and it takes about 2mins to output the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine that it is taking too long.  (How is this code not running in less than a second on an average laptop?)

If it is, you need to profile.

For example, a likely candidate is the cost of generating random numbers...

You'll only disprove me by profiling ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bit slow because it creates lots of temporary strings during the analysis phase.

```
for(int i = 0; i < order; i++){
    input.get(ch);
    key+=ch; // key = key + ch, at least one new string created
}
while(input.get(ch)){
    model[key].add(ch); // key copied to hash table
    key = key.substr(1,key.length()-1) + ch; // a couple of temp strings created
}
```

You could do instead like this:

```
char key[order + 1]; // pseudo code, won't work because order is not constant
key[order] = 0; /* NUL terminate */
for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
    input.get(key[i]);
}
while (!(input.eof())) {
    for (int j = 0; j < order - 1; k++) { 
        key[j] = key[j + 1];
    }
    input.get(key[order]);
    model[key].add(ch);
}
```

Here the only string that is actually created is the string that ends up as a key in the hash table. The key is rotated in a simple character array, avoiding string temporaries.